# MongoDB - Spring data - How to ignore the property name of a Map?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

We're using MongoDB with Spring data and we would like to have below structure for a certain collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("533e525bbd40c5da7cd8c3f0"),
"_class" : "net.someClass.SomeClass",
"source_id" : "other_id",
"name" : {
    "NL" : "iets",
    "FR" : "quelque chose"
    }
}
```

But due to the fact that our "name" is a custom class "TranslatableString" which contains an attribute TreeMap, mongoDB is representing a level in between:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("533e525bbd40c5da7cd8c3f0"),
"_class" : "net.someClass.SomeClass",
"source_id" : "other_id",
"name" : {
    "translations" : {
        "NL" : "iets",
        "FR" : "quelque chose"
        }
    }
}
```

Class TranslatableString:

```
public class TranslatableString {

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1)
private TreeMap<LanguageEnum, String> translations = new TreeMap<>();

public TranslatableString() {
    // empty default constructor
.............
}
```

Is there a possibility to ignore this property by using a Spring data annotation?
I know the existence of @Transient but this is ignoring the complete "name" attribute and it's content..

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use a MongoConverter.

First, you have to [configure the MongoConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#mapping-configuration) in the Spring context.

And so, you need two converters: one to store an objects in database, and one to query a documents from database. Something like that:

1) ReadConverter

```
public class SomeClassReadConverter implements Converter<DBObject, SomeClass> {

  public SomeClass convert(DBObject source) {
    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
      //do something...
    TranslatableString nameObj = new TranslatableString();
    nameObj.setTranslations((Map) source.get("name")); 
    obj.setName(nameObj);
      //do something...
    return obj;
  }

}
```

2) WriteConverter

```
public class SomeClassWriteConverter implements Converter<SomeClass, DBObject> {

  public DBObject convert(SomeClass source) {
    DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
       // do something...
    dbo.put("name", source.getName().getTranslations());
      // do something...
    return dbo;
  }

}
```